# How can I sign in via api using Devise in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Devise gem for auth and **gem 'devise_token_auth'** for api auth. 
In my routes I defined the following

```
  devise_for :users

  # token auth routes available at /api/v1/auth
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
```

But now I trying to sign in using curl and get an error:
My request for simple devise auth

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d "{'user' : { 'email' : 'admin@mail.ru', 'password' : 'r465ee'}}" -c cookie
```

Error

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::Parse Error in Devise::SessionsController#create
```

The same for the auth scope route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
```

means you mounted the engine on `/auth` path. `/users/sign_in` is the original devise(session/cookies based) login path. Also you don't need to use `-c cookie` anymore because it's token based.

Try

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in -d "{'user' : { 'email' : 'admin@mail.ru', 'password' : 'r465ee'}}"
```

or including namespace and scope

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in -d "{'user' : { 'email' : 'admin@mail.ru', 'password' : 'r465ee'}}"
```

Comment: This is native from devise or is using devise_token_auth?

Comment: It's using devise_token_auth.

Comment: Got an error again (large html response): <h1>
    ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError
      in DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create
  </h1>
</header>

<div id="container">
  <h2>822: unexpected token at &#39;{&#39;user&#39; : { &#39;email&#39; : &#39;admin@mail.ru&#39;, &#39;password&#39; : &#39;r465ee&#39;}}&#39;</h2>

Comment: raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Comment: try adding `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` to your application controller.